# Calling inline functions C++

Tags: c++, inline-method

I have an inline member function defined under class MyClass

```
int MyClass::myInlineFunction();
```

This function is called from several places in my code.
There are two ways to call this function
Case 1: Using this every time the function is called.

```
 mobj->myInlineFunction() ;
```

Case 2: Assign the result of this function to a variable and use it for subsequent accesses

```
 var = mobj->myInlineFunction() ;
```

Which one should be preferred??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Case 2 can give you a lot of performance, if the function does something that takes some time.
Choose it if

- you do not need side effects of the function to happen
- the function would always the return the same result in that context

Answer (score 1):

The decision on whether to hold onto a return value or to recall the function again, should not be based on whether the function is inlined or not - as this is an implementation detail that may change over the lifetime/evolution of the class. As a rule of thumb I would always hang onto the return value if it does not make the code too complicated, as you do not know as a user of a class, what the cost of the function is - and what is cheap today could be expensive tomorrow. So I would go with Case 2.

Comment: "what is cheap today could be expensive tomorrow". True, although more frequently it's the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

I would use Case 2 even if performance is not a problem. If all you care is the result of this function, then assigning it to a variable allows you later to easily switch to another method of obtaining this result.

Answer (score 0):

I can not understand the relation between inlining the function and assigning it to a function pointer as I understand.

### But for sure, the first way is self-documenting.

EDIT ::
Thanks Ahmed,

It depends actually and one can not always be used instead of the other way.

Again, the first way is clearer for me at least, if both work.

Comment: he assigns the result of the function (return value) not the function itself

Answer (score 0):

If the function returns the same result for every call, you have to use case 2 as it does not make sense to use case 1 even if it is inline function

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatly there isn't one simple answer, it depends on the function.

If the function is trivial, something like { return 6; }, just call it each time. The compiler will inline the call and remove the code. You should find no difference between assigning it to a variable, or not.

If the function is more complex, then it might be worth assigning it to a variable. Is the value constant throughout the program? Then maybe add to the class a static member which contains the value?

Answer (score 0):

Optimizing without knowing what or where usually ends up with more complex code that is not faster than the original.

To me the criteria to determine what solution to use is not based in the information that you provide.

- If the method is an accessor (just returns an internal value, as in std::vector<>::size() ) then make it inline and do not cache the result.
- If the method does perform significant work, don't make it inline and measure (you cannot measure an inlined method) how many times it is called, what cost it represents. Then decide if caching or inlining is apropriate.
- Caching the result (your case 2) can be an improvement for expensive methods, but only if the value is guaranteed not to change between the uses, and in this case I would not make the method inlined.
- You must cache the result if if affects your algorithm negatively (create memory based on the result and then use that memory checking overruns with that same result, if the value changes you will overrun your buffer)